# Spring Boot JPA One-to-One mapping generates StackOverflow Error

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa-2.0, one-to-one

Trying to run Spring-Boot JPA on MySQL and literally followed this tutorial here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/
All went well as expected.

However, moment I brought in a new Entity viz. Address of the User and established 1-to-1 unidirectional mapping, the Application starts to throw StackOverFlow error - even though the mapping is very basic that I have used without issues on App Servers (e.g GlassFish/Payara 5) several times.

Below is the mapping :

In `User` Entity

```java
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

..the other side of the relationship i.e. in `Address` :

```java
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
private User user;
```

Expected : A single line : `{"id":1,"name":"First","email":"someemail@someemailprovider.com","address":{"id":2,"line1":"Line1","postcode":"PST CD","city":"City","state":"State","country":"IN"`

Actual : The above line being printed on console countless times this there is a StackOverflow Error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean  "Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)".

You might need to add @JsonIgnore to the mapping parameters(Above your onetoone relationship) to stop looping.

Comment: But how does the @JsonIgnore magic works?? It works no doubt but not very intuitive!

Comment: I'm suspecting that the serializer trying to convert the object graph doesn't know that it is navigating through the same objects again and again. Thus yielding a stack overflow error.

Comment: user.address -> Instance of Address, Address.user -> Instance of User